# Array of file names needs sorting

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

My php script outputs an unsorted array as shown below. However, I need the file names sorted numerically in ascending order. Please provide the necessary code for outputting these files in a numerically sorted array. Thanks (I'm a beginner).

Unsorted output of my php script:

```
var galleryarray=new Array();
galleryarray[0]="Flower4.jpg";
galleryarray[1]="Flower5.jpg";
galleryarray[2]="Flower1.jpg";
galleryarray[3]="Flower2.jpg";
galleryarray[4]="Flower3.jpg";
```

Here's the php script that generated the above unsorted array:

```
<?php
//PHP SCRIPT: getimages.php
Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");

//This function gets the file names of all images in the current directory
//and outputs them as a JavaScript array
function returnimages($dirname=".") {
$pattern="/Flower*/"; //valid file name
$files = array(); 
$curimage=0;
if($handle = opendir($dirname)) {
    while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
        if (preg_match($pattern, $file)){ //if this file has a valid name
            //Output it as a JavaScript array element
            echo 'galleryarray['.$curimage.']="'.$file .'";';
            $curimage++;
            }
        }

        closedir($handle);
    }
    return($files);
}

echo 'var galleryarray=new Array();'; //Define array in JavaScript
returnimages() //Output the array elements containing the image file names

?>
```

Comment: Use the `natsort()` function.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a beginner, though, and don't know much about coding yet. If possible, please provide the exact coding. I'm hoping there's an easy way to sort this array, perhaps one that I can understand.

Comment: I already closed the question with a link to a similar question that shows how to get all the filenames and sort them.

Comment: I hope closing a question doesn't mean that others can't respond to my inquiry.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it means. If there's already an answer in another question, there's no point in answering it again.

Comment: If you don't think the other question really answers your question, update the question to show how it's a different problem, and I'll reopen so someone can provide the answer.

Comment: I suppose I better start learning more about the natsort() function!

Comment: Just put all the filenames in an array, and call `natsort($array)`

Comment: There's no need for a loop to assign each array element. Use `echo 'galleryarray = ' . json_encode($array) . ';';`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Barmar. Unfortunately, my lack of coding knowledge is causing me to lose sleep.

Comment: You can't expect us to do your coding for you. Show what you tried and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: I understand. I'll start researching your solutions tomorrow. Thanks, again, Barmar, for pointing me in the right direction.